# Solution Helmholtz equation in 1D with boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the equation

$$\phi''(x) +k^2 \phi(x)=-s(x)$$

with boundary conditions

$$\phi(0)=\phi(1)=0$$

and $k=\pi$ and $s(x)=\delta(x-0.5)$. I have done so through the weak form:

$$\int_0^1 \phi'(x) \psi'(x) -[k^2\phi(x)+s(x)]\psi(x) dx =0$$

and found the following solution numerically.

[image]

It does not seem correct and I would like to compare it to the analytical solution. Could someone tell me where I can find the analytical solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of a Green function. The solution left and right is a homogeneous solution. Where they meet at $x=0.5$ the derivative needs to have a jump of $-1$ so that the second derivative has the delta distribution of the correct size. So
$$
ϕ(x)=\begin{cases}c\sin(kx),&x\in[0,0.5],\\c\sin(k(1-x)),&x\in[0.5,1].\end{cases}
$$
with
$$
ϕ'(0.5+0)=-1+ϕ'(0.5-0)\\
-ck\cos(0.5k)=-1+ck\cos(0.5k)\\
\implies c=\frac1{2k\cos(0.5k)}
$$
In the case $k=\pi$ you do not get such a solution. The numerical solution may correspond to the exact solution for a near-by value of $k$, getting large values is thus to be expected.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot already. I have updated the question with the weak form of the differential equation, is the expected solution the same?

Comment: You could replace $\int_0^1s(x)\psi(x)dx=-\psi(0.5)$ to be fully inside variational calculus. And yes, that should give the same solution if $\psi$ is unrestricted. If $\phi$ and $\psi$ are restricted to some subspace of the overall Sobolev space, then you get of course other solutions and other critical frequencies.